# How to add listview in an image button?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

I wanted to add a listview in an image button in such a way that when i clicked the button the information which is present in the listview should display in the next page. Could anyone help me with this??

[image]

see this is how it should be if i click on any of these buttons it has to list the information and that to be displayed in the next activity not in the same

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add view to another view. You can to viewGroup, but not to view. So i would suggest you to take a screenshot of your listview (which you will have to create it first, or you should figure something else out) and then set that image into imageButton.

Comment: i have posted the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can use tabhost to create tabs with the images. Plz take a look at the following tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636403/MonoAndroid-Using-TabHost-in-your-mobile-applicati)

[Tutorial 3](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Inside each tab you can place the custom list view.